# GRUB does not remember root file system location

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I wiped my old Ubuntu OS and installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (alongside Windows 10) from a USB device to replace it. When I first booted into it after installation, the GRUB menu did not load, but it opened the GRUB CLI instead. I've learned that this is due to GRUB not finding the root file system. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/) to configure GRUB from its CLI. Everything went alright and I was able to boot into Ubuntu. After successfully running `sudo update-grub` and `sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1` and rebooting, GRUB still opened the CLI instead of loading the menu like it should. I have no idea why GRUB doesn't remember these configurations. Is there a way to manually change the files so that the boot menu is loaded correctly?

If it helps, this is how my partitions look like:

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0          7:0    0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
loop1          7:1    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop2          7:2    0  64,8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop3          7:3    0  31,1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11036
loop4          7:4    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/518
loop5          7:5    0  99,4M  1 loop /snap/core/11316
loop6          7:6    0  61,7M  1 loop /snap/core20/1026
loop7          7:7    0 207,1M  1 loop /snap/code/67
loop8          7:8    0 301,5M  1 loop /snap/telegram-desktop/2814
loop9          7:9    0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2074
loop10         7:10   0  32,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12398
loop11         7:11   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop12         7:12   0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop13         7:13   0  65,1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
nvme0n1      259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1  259:1    0   500M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2  259:2    0   128M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3  259:3    0 290,1G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4  259:4    0  78,1G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5  259:5    0   932M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p6  259:6    0  12,2G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p7  259:7    0   1,1G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p8  259:8    0     1M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p9  259:9    0   513M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p10 259:10   0  23,3G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p11 259:11   0  70,1G  0 part /home
```

Comment: Probably you need to set the correct boot at UEFI. I suspect you're booting the old installation.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Alright, here's the report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gnN6TgD49v/

Answer (score -1):

The UEFI mode should have a mount of the EFI partiion at /boot/efi -- you don't.  Without that mount, there is no way to update /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg, which is the three line stub which brings in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg from your root.  You can find the UUID of the EFI partition with

```
sudo blkids
```

Then just edit the EFI's grub.cfg and use that UUID (and change any old disk/partition reference hints too).
Or just fix the EFI mount in /etc/fstab with a line like:

```
UUID=xxxx-yyyy  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

Using the UUID for the EFI partition.
Then run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1
```

Check/add that the boot flag is on the EFI partition, and you should be all set.